# Edit ASMX web service landing page wording/information?

Tags: web-services, asmx

Is there a way to edit/add some information to the asmx web service page? I would like to add some links to some external files that is helpful for the service. Currently, it's displaying something like this:

> My Web Services
>
> The following operations are
>   supported. For a formal definition,
>   please review the Service Description.
>
> TestMethod

I would like to add a link after the "`TetsMethod`". Thanks.

Comment: WCF doesn't even _have_ the test page. It's not terribly useful. What did you want it for?

Comment: I'm using the good old asmx web service. I just want people, when accessing the service from the web interface (i.e, mydomain.com/service.asmx), they'll present with some additional information beside the methods that I exposes. But it doesn't seem to be possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and found the wsdlHelpGenerator element in web.config could help me out.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ycx1yf7k(v=vs.100).aspx

I took the source code of the generated help page, hand edited what I needed into it, and saved it as a static html file that I then hooked up to the wsdlHelpGenerator element:

```html
<webServices>
  ...
  <wsdlHelpGenerator href="help.html"/>
  ...
</webServices>
```

I also needed to add the following to my system.web section:

```html
<system.web>
  ...
  <compilation>
    <buildProviders>
      <add extension=".html" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider" />
    </buildProviders>
  </compilation>
  ...
</system.web>
```